# dreamweaver "single quote comments"

Tags: dreamweaver, comments

I am using Dreamweaver CC. I see that in the coding toolbar on the right of the
open document window there is a button which when hovered displays the text
"Apply Comment". When I click on it I can recognize all comment types instead
of the single quote (') comment style. I know html, css, javascript, sql and
php, but I am curious as to what languages are recognized by dreamweaver and
use the single quote comment (commenting out by placing the ' character at
the beginning of the line). Just curious.

Comment: It seems only Basic-derived languages use these, so look for which of them is/are supported by your editor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28syntax%29#Comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the BASIC-derived language that Dreamweaver used to support is VBScript which
can be used in place of C# in Asp.NET applications. Nowadays Dreamweaver CC does not offer
the option to create Asp.NET or ColdFusion pages from its splash screen (although three
relatively new entries can be found for LESS, Sass, and Scss which are stylesheet languages
not supported in older versions of DreamWeaver. Nevertheless, the "Apply Comment" button in
the coding toolbar still displays this single quote dinosaur-comment.

Regards.